# Error: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: vb.net

```
        myconnection() 'open connection

        sql = "UPDATE tblbankposting SET BankEntryDate=@date,@BankName=@name,BankCode=@code,AccountNo=@acc"
        sql &= ",TransactionType=@type,Amount=@amount,BankCharges=@charges,@ReferenceNo=@ref,Description=@des "
        sql &= "WHERE TransactionID=@id"

        command = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
        With command
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@id", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "TransactionID"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@date", OleDbType.DBDate, 30, "BankEntryDate"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@name", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "BankName"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@code", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "BankCode"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@acc", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "AccountNo"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@type", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "TransactionType"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@amount", OleDbType.Double, 10, "Amount"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@charges", OleDbType.Double, 10, "BankCharges"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ref", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "ReferenceNo"))
            .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@des", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "Description"))
            'set parameter values
            .Parameters("@id").Value = txttxnid.Text
            .Parameters("@date").Value = CDate(dtpbankentrydate.Value.Date)
            .Parameters("@name").Value = cbobanks.Text
            .Parameters("@code").Value = txtbankcode.Text
            .Parameters("@acc").Value = cboaccno.Text
            .Parameters("@type").Value = cbotxntype.Text
            .Parameters("@amount").Value = CDbl(txtamount.Text)
            .Parameters("@charges").Value = CDbl(txtbankcharges.Text)
            .Parameters("@ref").Value = txtrefno.Text
            .Parameters("@des").Value = txtdescription.Text
        End With
```

i get the error no value given for one or more required parameters.The parameters worked fine while saving but unable to update.

Comment: Your SET has four parameters while you added ten parameters. Your parameters count should match the parameters in the SET.

Comment: What is the type of TransactionID in the Db? is it really varchar?

Comment: This part of your query looks strange:  `@BankName=@name`.  Perhaps you meant `BankName=@name`  Also should `@ReferenceNo=@ref` be `ReferenceNo=@ref`?  Also you should probably mention what database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra @ next to your Field BankName and ReferenceNo

**@BankName=@name**
**@ReferenceNo=@ref**

```
myconnection() 'open connection

sql = "UPDATE tblbankposting SET BankEntryDate=@date,BankName=@name,BankCode=@code,AccountNo=@acc"
sql &= ",TransactionType=@type,Amount=@amount,BankCharges=@charges,ReferenceNo=@ref,Description=@des "
sql &= "WHERE TransactionID=@id"

command = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
With command
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@id", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "TransactionID"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@date", OleDbType.DBDate, 30, "BankEntryDate"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@name", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "BankName"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@code", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "BankCode"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@acc", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "AccountNo"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@type", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "TransactionType"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@amount", OleDbType.Double, 10, "Amount"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@charges", OleDbType.Double, 10, "BankCharges"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ref", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "ReferenceNo"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@des", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "Description"))
    'set parameter values
    .Parameters("@id").Value = txttxnid.Text
    .Parameters("@date").Value = CDate(dtpbankentrydate.Value.Date)
    .Parameters("@name").Value = cbobanks.Text
    .Parameters("@code").Value = txtbankcode.Text
    .Parameters("@acc").Value = cboaccno.Text
    .Parameters("@type").Value = cbotxntype.Text
    .Parameters("@amount").Value = CDbl(txtamount.Text)
    .Parameters("@charges").Value = CDbl(txtbankcharges.Text)
    .Parameters("@ref").Value = txtrefno.Text
    .Parameters("@des").Value = txtdescription.Text
End With
```

Comment: Thanks had missed that